# SSH port only open after connecting ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ethernet, port

I am having a weird issue:

It all started when I bought a really cheap wireless card off f E-Bay ($1.30).

It took me 3 days to finally get the drivers half working (half working because it connects to the internet, but the device is called `wlx00e62d021fe4`, instead of `wlan0` or `wlp13s0`).

I installed `wpa_supplicant`, and connected to my WiFi access point, here is my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="Telstra8D49DA"
    #psk="************"
    psk=****************************************************************
}
```

(Passwords blanked for obvious reasons :P)

And here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlx00e62d021fe4
iface wlx00e62d021fe4 inet dhcp
```

And I made a service in `/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service`, with the following contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Run dhclient wlx00e62d021fe4 at startup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient wlx00e62d021fe4
ExecStop=
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

And it runs at boot with the following command:

```
# systemctl enable dhcpcd
```

However, unless the Ethernet cord is/or has been plugged in, none of my ports are open.

Here are some `NMAP` outputs:

Without Ethernet:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-10 14:46 AEDT
Nmap scan report for UbuntuServer (10.0.0.129)
Host is up (0.0076s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on UbuntuServer (10.0.0.129) are closed
MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:** (*******)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.52 seconds
```

With Ethernet:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-10 14:58 AEDT
Nmap scan report for UbuntuServer (10.0.0.129)
Host is up (0.0025s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:** (*** *** ********* ****)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.34 seconds
```

After unplugging Ethernet:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-10 14:59 AEDT
Nmap scan report for UbuntuServer (10.0.0.129)
Host is up (0.0095s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:** (*******)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.58 seconds
```

And here is the output of `uname -a`

```
Linux UbuntuServer 4.13.0-19-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 11:58:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also, all packages are updated. I always update with this command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

The server can still connect to the internet, shown when I type `ping 8.8.8.8`, and is 'ping-able' (My computer pinging it with `ping 10.0.0.129`) without the Ethernet cord plugged in, so its just my ports.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the card?

Comment: what address is the sshd listening on? with the cord plugged in, `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 22`. unless it is listening on 0.0.0.0 or the  wifi card's IP, it won't work.